# Probability of a sequence of random letters

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose an the letters of  a  random sequence  are chosen independently and uniformly  from the set of 26 English alphabet .If the sequence contains n letters what is the probability that it contains  the word "Love" as a  subsequence?Thanks a lot for nay help in advance

Answer (score 1):

The way of dealing with such questions is to think clearly about what is involved. Suppose I am looking for the word "the". Let the probablity that it appears in the first $n$ letters be $p_n$.

Now if "the" appears, either it appears in the first $n-1$ letters, or it appears for the first time at the $n^{th}$ letter. In this case the last three letters chosen are "the" with probability $\frac 1{26^3}$, and the first $n-3$ letters do not contain the word "the".

I am left with $$p_n=p_{n-1}+\frac 1{26^3}(1-p_{n-3})$$ and $p_0=p_1=p_2=0$. This is now a recurrence which can be explicitly solved.

---

If I were looking for the single letter "a" the same approach would give me $p_n=p_{n-1}+\frac 1{26}(1-p_{n-1})$ or $p_n = \frac {25}{26}p_{n-1}+\frac 1{26}$

The solution to this is $p_n=1+A\left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^n$ and $p_0=0$ gives $A=-1$, which checks with simpler ways of computing, which are available for a single letter.

Answer (score -1):

The total number of appearances of letters in 4 spaces is $26^4=456976$. Since there is only one case, which is $\mathcal{love}$, the probability of $\mathcal{love}$ appearing in a $4$ letter sequence is $1\over456976$.

Since in $n$ blank spaces there are $n-3$ groups of $4$ consecutive blank spaces, the probability is ${n-3}\over{456976}$.

Comment: And what is the probability for $n=10^6$ using this calculation?

Comment: You make your point quite well.

Answer (score -3):

The total number of combinations is $n!$

The total number of combinations including the word 'love' is $(n-3)!$
This is because we can treat the sequence of the four letters 'love' as one object, so there are only n-3 to arrange.

so $P($String contains 'love'$) = (n-3)!/(n)! = 1/(n*(n-1)*(n-2))$

Comment: Isn't this a conditional probability problem?Shouldn't you consider the case where the letters l,o,v,e are there in the set on n?

Comment: The total number of combinations is not $n!$ but rather $26^n$. Your post is wrong.

Comment: Also you overlook that it is not forbidden that "love" occurs more than once if $n\geq8$. That demands to be careful to avoid multiple counting.